# Taking string input

Tags: c++

How to take string input in C++?

I generally use gets. But is doesn't work for 2-D arrays.
On the other hand cin ignores the text after a blank.
I want the input to be the exact unformatted text.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709452/how-to-read-string-from-keyboard-using-c.

Comment: Rahul's suggestion can also be used with `std::string` by omitting second parameter from `getline()` function..

Comment: "I generally use puts." ---- puts do not take string in. You probably mean gets.

Comment: I don't get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think the question need to be explained with more detail about "2-D arrays" and "exact unformatted text".

Comment: I mean 2-D string. Unformatted text means the exact input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:-

```
char input[100];
cin.getline(input,100);
```

Check out the [cin.getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Comment: Thanks 
For 2-D arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by 2-D array?

Comment: @Level31: If you are asking for a special function that can work with 2 dimensional `char` or `std::string` arrays, there is none in the standard library. You can always use `std::vector` with `for_each` STL algorithm to automize such behavior.