# Query user to continue printing in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program that starts printing at 0.
It prints up to 15 and asks the user a **y/n** question.

- if **y** that program prints next 15.
- if **n** program stops.

The program I wrote does not work.

Help solving this.

```
int main()
{
int i=0,k=1;
char ans;

while(k=1)
{
    i++;
    printf("\n%d",i);

    if(i%15==0)
    {
        printf("\nDo you want to continue?(y/n): ");
        scanf("%c",ans);
        ans = toupper(ans);
        if(ans=='Y') {
            continue;
        }
        else if(ans=='N') {
            k=0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

----------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------
changed the code as @Programmer400.  Also 15-->3. Now my computer prints

```
1
2
3
Do you want to continue?(y/n): y

4
5
6
Do you want to continue?(y/n): 
7
8
9
Do you want to continue?(y/n): y
```

First it prints till 3 and asks. After Y, it prints till 6 and asks and then without any input prints till 9 and asks. Note the missing y in the 2nd question.

Comment: `while(k=1)` --> `while(k==1)` and `scanf("%c",ans)` --> `scanf(" %c",&ans)`

Comment: `i++; printf("\n%d",i);` --> `printf("\n%d",i++);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided a working C program below that performs the tasks you specified in your question.

I have taken an effort to stay true to the functions that you used in your original code sample and I have also taken care to only make additions (not remove code).

In the comments, I have explained lines of code that I have added that were not in your original code sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
        int i = 0, k = 1;
        char user_input;
        char ans;

        while(k == 1)
        {
                i++;
                printf("%d\n", i);

                if (i % 15 == 0)
                {
                        printf("Do you want to continue? (y/n/Y/N): ");
                        scanf(" %c",&user_input); // Keep the whitespace in front of the %c format specifier -- it's important!
                        getchar(); // Consume the newline character left in the buffer by scanf()

                        // Check if user input is already capitalized
                        if (user_input >= 65 && user_input <= 90)
                                // If it is, keep it capitalized
                                ans = user_input;
                        else
                                // If it isn't, capitalize it
                                ans = toupper(user_input);

                        if (ans=='Y')
                        {
                                // Allow the loop to continue
                                continue;
                        }
                        else if (ans == 'N')
                        {
                                // Inform the user that execution is ending
                                printf("Exiting loop... ending program.\n");
                                // Consider removing 'k' entirely, just use a 'break' statement
                                k = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Inform the user that the input was not recognized (if not y/n/Y/N...)    
                            printf("User input not recognized... please provide input again.\n");
                                // Decrement 'i' so that the user is forced to provide input again...
                                i--;
                                // Allow the loop to continue
                                continue;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

**Helpful notes**:

1. `scanf` leaves a newline character in the buffer when you are reading user input with character formatters. Namely...

   > `%c`, `%n`, and `%[]` are the 3 specified expectations that do not consume leading whitespace
   >   -- From a comment on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/5209610).
2. Keep in mind that if you would like to exit your `while` loop, you could simply insert a `break` statement. This way, you don't have to change the value of `k` (which is rather ambiguous) to end the loop and the code is more readable because an explicit `break` statement is harder to misinterpret. In this *simple* case, the use of `k` is easily understood (so don't worry about it too much, for now).
3. If you ever intend to read string input from a user (i.e., an array of characters), then I would recommend that you use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. A discussion of the merits of `fgets()` in comparison to `scanf()` is provided in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709467/5209610). Further, it is important to recognize that even though you *can* use `gets()` to perform a similar operation it is highly dangerous and never advised. Check out the explanations provided by the [top two answers to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/5209610).

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing your code so that it doesn't generate warnings, now it seems to "work" (but maybe it can be even more correct).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,k=1;;
    char c;
    char ans[] = "";
    while(k==1)
    {
        i++;
        printf("\n%d",i);

        if(i%15==0)
        {
            printf("\nDo you want to continue?(y/n): ");
            scanf(" %c",ans);
            ans[0] = (char) toupper(ans[0]);
            if(ans[0]=='Y') {
                continue;
            }
            else if(ans[0]=='N') {
                k=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```