# how to take a birth date format as a input with string in c programming

Tags: c, input, c-strings, string-parsing

what is the best away to take a date format as input .like this..
dd/mm/yyyy.
i do not like to use scanf("%d/%d/%d.........);

Comment: I don't understand the question. Input as a string is done using `fgets` (better don't use `gets`). If you insist on `scanf`, you might want to take a closer look at the %s format specifier in the man page.

Comment: `char date[10]; scanf("%s", date);`

Comment: **Never ever** use `gets`. It is not part of the standard anymore and a first class security risk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read string from keyboard using C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709452/how-to-read-string-from-keyboard-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid `gets()` to prevent buffer overflow.

Instead use the safest `fgets()`

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)`
>
> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Then you can use `int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);` which

> reads its input from the character string pointed to by str.

Here is an example program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char date_of_birth[MAXLEN];
    int day_of_birth, month_of_birth, year_of_birth;

    fgets(date_of_birth, MAXLEN, stdin);
    
    sscanf(date_of_birth,"%d %*c %d %*c %d", &day_of_birth, &month_of_birth, &year_of_birth);
    
    printf("\nDay of birth : %d\nMonth of birth : %d\nYear of birth : %d\n", day_of_birth, month_of_birth, year_of_birth);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.
If you want to know how to take date input using scanf , here is how it is done.

```
int d,m,y;                   //This is your code.
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d,&m,&y);  //Now this tells that scanf expect input in this format.
```

If you give input `23/4/12` , This will  store `23` in `d` , `4` in `m` and `12` in `y`.

Never Take input using `gets()` and `scanf()` as they does not check buffer overflow , and `gets()` has been removed from the standard way long back. It is a well known security risk.

Instead use fgets`()`.Note `fgets()` also stores the ending new line character, to remove it I have used the following method below.

To take this input using `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

         char date[10];

         fgets(date,10,stdin);

         int i = 0;
         //Now For Removing new line character from end of the string.
         while(date[i]!='\0'){     

             if(date[i]=='\n'){
                        date[i] = '\0';
                        break;
                      }

            i++;
         }

         }
```