# segmentation fault in passing a char* pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to make a program which checks whether the entered string is palindrome or not using recursion. Here is the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPalindrome(char* s, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= j)
        return 1;

    if (s[i] != s[j])
        return 0;

    return isPalindrome(s, i+1, j-1);
}

int main() {

    char* word;
    printf("Enter a word \n");
    scanf("%s", word);

    if (isPalindrome(word, 0, strlen(word) - 1))
        printf("Palindrome \n");
    else
        printf("Not Palindrome \n");

    return 0;
}
```

The program seems to give a segmentation fault caused by the function isPalindrome(). Where is my code going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);` invokes *undefined behavior* - you need to initialize the pointer `word` to point at valid (and sufficient) memory first

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `word`--it's just a pointer.

Comment: as said no memory allocated for `word`, you can change it for example like `char word [80];`

Comment: How did you determine the fault was inside `isPalindrome`? The `scanf` should have failed first.

Comment: Here is the **real duplicate**.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709452  I don't know if there's an easy way to correct a vague duplicate to a more accurate one.

Comment: The descriptions of the error above are more complicated than necessary. It's this simple: You have to assign a variable a value before passing its value to a function. You do not assign `word` a value, but you pass its value to `scanf`.

Comment: @DrewDormann a gold-badge holder can *edit* the duplicates

Comment: @DrewDormann fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a character pointer, You should either have another character string which has been allocated and make it point to that

OR you directly dynamically allocate space for a string.

Your code works if you malloc some space

```
char *word = malloc(20);
```

or you can just create a string

```
char word[20];
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks a lot.